# Need a free datepicker for ASPX

Tags: asp.net, date, datepicker

What is the best FREE Datepicker that can be dropped into an ASPX application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an excellent, free package that will AJAX enable the calendar control for use as a date picker.

Here's the video tutorial: http://www.asp.net/LEARN/ajax-videos/video-124.aspx

Answer (score 7):

[jQuery UI Datepicker](http://marcgrabanski.com/pages/code/jquery-ui-datepicker)

[ASP.NET AJAX has a good one too](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I use [Basic Date Picker](http://www.basicdatepicker.com/) and swear by it.  We use the pay version, but there is a free version which probably includes all of the features that we use.

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio has one built-in.

Answer (score 1):

I've long used Excentric's World UI tools: http://www.eworldui.net/

Answer (score 1):

It's not an ASP.NET solution, but there's a great Javascript date picker at http://www.frequency-decoder.com/2006/10/02/unobtrusive-date-picker-widgit-update. You implement it by setting a couple of CSS classes on an input field. Have used this many times and think it's great!

Answer (score 1):

[Ra-Ajax Calendar control](http://ra-ajax.org/samples/Ajax-Calendar.aspx) a great sample of usage is the Ajax Calendar Starter-Kit which can bee seen [here](http://ra-ajax.org/samples/Viewport-Calendar-Starter-Kit.aspx) which I think shows the flexibility of it quite well...

And it's LGPL meaning Free of Charge...